# Java constructor examples

Tags: java, constructor

I'm seeing some examples and I will like to understand deeply what's the difference of creating a object by `this.repository=repository` in the constructor or using  `Repository repository = new Repository()`

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
  private final Repository repository
  public ServiceImpl (Repository repository)
      this.repository=repository     
 }
```

Comment: Simple difference: `this.repository=repository` is not an object creation.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.repository= new Repository()
```

creating a repository object and assigning it to **instance variable**, which can be accessed anywhere from the class

```
Repository repository = new Repository()
```

it will create a **local variable** and it will be accessible only inside that method

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the repository object has been created outside the ServiceImpl and passed in. In the second case, the ServiceImpl is creating the repository object.

Which is correct really depends on whether you think the ServiceImpl object should control creation of the repository. If the repository is passed in, the calling code could pass in a subclass of repository, rather than Repository itself, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The line `this.repository=repository` does not create new `Repository` object, all it does it assign `parameter` repository to instance variable `repository`.

To create a new `Repository` object, you need to invoke the `constructor`

`Repository r = new Repository()`

Answer (score 0):

`Repository repository = new Repository()` declares a reference handler repository which points to a newly created Repository object

`this` keyword refers to the Object of class on which some method is invoked.

**NOTE:-** `this.repository=repository` is not an object creation.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor

```
public ServiceImpl (Repository repository)
  this.repository= new Repository();
}
```

to create an Object its constructor should be used with the `new` keyword.
that is how the language semantics is designed.

you cannot create an object like this `this.repository = repository`. it just assigns the existing object referenced by the Object reference repository. or null if its not initiallized